# How can I make "Ink Free" font bold in InkScape

Tags: inkscape, bold

So just downloaded InkSpace for Windows, and there is a cool font I like "Ink Free"

The thing is it does not have the bold option in the dropdown.. Any ideas on how can I enable this op

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you can't select bold for a font, it means you haven't installed a bold version of the font. There's no way to enable it if doesn't exist, or hasn't been installed.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no bold version of the font. Tough luck.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is, with the text selected, click on the Fill and Stroke option and turn on Stroke ("Stroke paint"), then adjust the thickness ("Stroke style") to best approximate bold font.

You may have to adjust the spacing of the letters to get it just right.